# Why is return required in this code block?

Tags: scala

Below code just returns a random String via the `getFileName` method :

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer

object RTest extends App {

  var currentFileNameList: ListBuffer[String] = new ListBuffer

  def getFileName(): String = {
    var fileName = java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString();

    while (true) {
      if (!currentFileNameList.contains(fileName)) {
        currentFileNameList = currentFileNameList :+ fileName
        return fileName
      } else {
        fileName = java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString();
      }
    }

    throw new RuntimeException("Error - filename not generated")
  }

  println(getFileName())
}
```

If I remove the return statement in line : `return fileName` then the method `getFileName` appears to get caught in an infinite loop and does not terminate.

Why is the explicit return required ? Should the scala compiler not infer the return of var `fileName` ?

Comment: because otherwise you will proceed to next iteration? it's not about inferring something, it's about flow control in a first place

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As om-nom-nom already said in a comment, it's not really about the type inference, rather it's a control flow problem.

By using `return` you're breaking the (otherwise) infinite while loop.

---

Also, not really part of the question, but since you're using a random UUID, you can probably drop the duplicate-checking code and simply return the generated UUID as it is, unless you have insanely high requirements.

[According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Random_UUID_probability_of_duplicates),

> [the probability of generating a duplicate string] is about 0.00000000006 (6 × 10−11), equivalent to the odds of creating a few tens of trillions of UUIDs in a year and having one duplicate.

In a "normal" case I would simply do

```
def getFileName: String = java.util.UUID.randomUUID.toString
```

and be done with it.

Answer (score 2):

Because of this block...

```
 while (true) {
  if (!currentFileNameList.contains(fileName)) {
    currentFileNameList = currentFileNameList :+ fileName
    return fileName
  } else {
    fileName = java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString();
  }
}
```

You are in an endless loop, as "true" never changes. By returning the function you are jumping out of this loop (as well as completely out of the function).

You could do something like...

```
object RTest extends App {

    var currentFileNameList: ListBuffer[String] = new ListBuffer

    def getFileName(): String = {
        var fileName = java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString();

        while (currentFileNameList.contains(fileName)) {
            fileName = java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString();                    
        }
        currentFileNameList = currentFileNameList :+ fileName;
        return fileName;
    }

    println(getFileName())
}
```

Which should have the same effect.

Answer (score 2):

No loops, vars, or (explicit) recursion

```
def getFileName(): String = {
  val fileName = Iterator.continually(java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                         .find(!currentFileNameList.contains(_)).get
  currentFileNameList += fileName
  fileName
}
```

Comment: V nice use of continually.  Let us get you some points for this.

Answer (score 0):

You're not supposed to be looping or using vars:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer

object Test extends App {

  val currentFileNameList: ListBuffer[String] = new ListBuffer

  @annotation.tailrec
  def getFileName(): String = {
    val fileName = java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString();

    if (!currentFileNameList.contains(fileName)) {
      currentFileNameList += fileName
      fileName
    } else {
      getFileName()
    }
  }

  println(getFileName())
}
```